# Is it possible to see Path Spaces as manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Dear Sir/friends,

How to give manifold structure to set of all $C^2$ path over any manifold.

Comment: Please see http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask -as regarding your questtion, what you ask is easy in the smooth case, but the space of C^2 functions is much bigger. Work by Kriegl + Michor would be appropriate to consult: http://books.google.com.au/books?id=s7fPYRqhXEUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=kriegl+michor&hl=en&ei=PikITs2eBYPbmAWbo5DLDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false, chapter III section 12 may help. Note this is only for spaces of mappings into certain topological vector spaces. This is a necessary ingredient for the manifold case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "path" you mean a map with domain $[0,1]$ then this is a standard construction and is independent of the class of maps (providing it is contained in $C^0$).  You can find it in many places, search MathSciNet for "manifold" and "mapping space", or you can *almost* find it in my paper [Constructing Smooth Manifolds of Loop Spaces](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Research/Papers/smooth.html).  I deal with maps from $S^1$ there but there's no difference in the construction.

If by "path" you mean a map with domain $\mathbb{R}$ then it is much, much more complicated.  With the standard topology then it isn't a manifold.  You can put a topology on it to make it a manifold, but it has uncountably many components.  For more on this, look in Kriegl and Michor's book *A Convenient Setting for Global Analysis* (that also has the construction for $[0,1]$ for the smooth setting, which readily adapts to $C^2$).

Comment: snap! (but your answer is of course better)

Answer (score -1):

I give such a manifold structure here: [The tangent bundle to an infinite-dimensional manifold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65926/the-tangent-bundle-to-an-infinite-dimensional-manifold/65933#65933)