# Manifold structure of the set of all smooth functions between two smooth manifolds!

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

In the studies of the calculus of variation, a map $f:M\to N$ said to be harmonic if it is a critical point of the Dirichlet energy function. i. e.

\begin{align}
E:C^\infty(M,N)&\longrightarrow \Bbb R\\
f&\mapsto E(f)
\end{align}

In general, a point $p$ in $M_1$ is a critical point of $f:M_1\to M_2$ if the differential $f_{*p}:T_pM_1\to T_{f(p)}M_2$ fails to be surjective. If $M_2=\Bbb R$ then $f$ has a
critical point at $p \in M$ if and only if $(df)_p=0$.

How to show that $C^\infty(M,N)$ is an infinite dimensional smooth manifold and What is its tangent space at a point $f\in C^\infty(M,N)$?

Thanks.

Comment: [Peter Michor](http://mathoverflow.net/users/26935/peter-michor) will probably suggest that you go read his book (joint with Kriegl) [The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis](http://bookstore.ams.org/surv-53). The material is presented in Chapter IX, and the book itself is freely available on the authors' websites.

Comment: Are you assuming $M$ is compact? If not, then things get nasty...

Comment: @C.F.G the mapping space doesn't use the obvious topology (which doesn't give you a manifold) and the one you do use results in uncountably-many connected components (from the horse's mouth: http://mathoverflow.net/a/68907/4177)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the smooth case in *The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis* (by Andreas Kriegel & Peter Michor), Chapter IX, Manifolds of Mappings.

If you are also interested in the case $k<\infty$: $C^k(M,N)$ (where $M$ is compact and $N$ Riemannian) with the $C^k$-compact open topology is a $C^\infty$-Banach manifold. The tangent space at $f\in C^k(M,N)$ is given by $T_fC^k(M,N)=\Gamma_{C^k}(f^*TN)$ where on $\Gamma_{C^k}(f^*TN)$ one has the usual $C^k$-topology. The charts of $C^k(M,N)$ can be constructed with the exponential map of $N$.